# Build fails on mapped drive, but not locally

Tags: c#, msbuild, xna, monogame, mapped-drive

I'm working on a game written in C# using VS2013 and monogame. However, monogame doesn't support the XNA content pipeline (*still*), so the going advice is to build your content separately using Microsoft's XNA and VS2010. Since I didn't want to clutter my primary development machine (Win8) with VS2010 et cetera, I created a Win7 virtual machine to run Win7 along with VS2010 and all the tooling I need to build my content. All my project and solution files have corresponding 2010 versions, and the 2010 solution only has the necessary projects to build the content.

I can successfully build the content, but only if it's present direcly on the VM's hard disk (*C:\*). If I map a local drive to a network share on the host machine and attempt to build, I get a build time error. Why do I want to do this? Because I want a single copy of the source tree so I can iterate at a decent speed. It's just far too painful and error-prone if I have a separate source tree in the VM.

Here's the build error I get:

```
Error loading pipeline assembly "S:\Src\ContentPipelineExtension\bin\x86\Debug\Newtonsoft.Json.dll".
```

I have *S:\* mapped to my network share. *Newtonsoft.Json.dll* exists at the indicated path.

I have tried:

- specifying `/verbosity:d` when building to see if any more information is output. There isn't.
- attaching a debugger to the *MSBuild.exe* process with break on any exception enabled. It never breaks.
- using `subst` instead of Windows Explorer's drive mapping tool (it might be using `subst` behind the scenes, but I wanted to be sure).
- [debugging MSBuild](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/07/06/debugging-msbuild-script-with-visual-studio.aspx), but I hit the ["mismatched leave" bug](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2010/07/09/debugging-msbuild-script-with-visual-studio-3.aspx) when I did so.
- applied the workaround for the mismatched leave bug and debugged the build simultaneously on both *C:\* and *S:\*. In both cases, I put a breakpoint right before XNA's `BuildContent` task was called. I let both builds run until they hit this breakpoint, and then I opened the locals windows, side-by-side. I compared all locals and found no difference apart from the expected *C:\* versus *S:\* path roots.
- spelunking through the XNA code in ILSpy to try and figure out where it's going wrong, but have had no luck with that either
- enabling full trust on the network share in CAS by executing: `CasPol.exe -m -ag 1.2 -url file://S:\* FullTrust`. No change in behavior.
- enabling Fusion Log Viewer (`fuslogvw.exe`) and checking out its log. It says it has successfully loaded the assembly!
- added `<loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>` to my *MSBuild.exe.config*. No change.

**Why does the build fail when running off my mapped *S:\* and succeed when a copy of the source is placed on my *C:\*?**

**UPDATE:** I just found the most awful work-around. I modified my *ContentPipelineExtension* project's `Output Path` such that it is an absolute directory on my *C:\*. This allows the build to complete successfullly, but is obviously far from ideal.

Comment: Use diagnostic verbosity rather than detailed.

Comment: @Nick: just tried that and it does not output any more information regarding the specific error. I get `Task BuildContent` the line before the error, so the `BuildContent` task is just not outputting anything useful.

Comment: .NET and VS/MSBuild have always tried to limit trust of non-local code and have used different methods across versions. Perhaps this [article](http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2011/07/loading-blocked-and-network-hosted-assemblies-with-net-4.html) on  `loadFromRemoteSources` will help.

Comment: @Tom: thanks. Funnily enough, I was just experimenting with CAS. Please see my final two points in my "tried" list. Now checking out the article you linked to...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hack I used. It's not a satisfying answer (and I won't mark it as accepted), but in the absence of a better solution, it will save me an enormous amount of time and pain.

I edited my 2010 project files and changed my output paths to something like this:

```
<OutputPath>$(TEMP)\ContentPipelineExtension\bin\x86\Debug\</OutputPath>
```

The `TEMP` environment variable resolves to a folder on *C:\* and saves me hard-coding a specific path. Now I can build the project from my Win7 VM using the same source tree as I use in my primary Win8 machine.